# What fires 'touchmove' event?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I've been debugging a touchmove event and 'console.logging it', yet I still don't get and still haven't found any information on how does this event actually get fired.

So is this event fired based on distance/time, both?, When is this fired?

Comment: well,javascript intercepts events.There is obviously some hardware involved in it.

Comment: It's fired if something is moved, this cannot happen in zero time; what is it you're trying to solve, or is this a 'simple' theoretical question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact implementation depends on the user agent, as can be read in the specification on [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/) in section 5.5 the touchmove event

Comment: I didn't put much attention to that line, yet it's nice to know. Now my search will be "How each user agent fires the touchmove event?" :)

Comment: yes I guess you'll find it in their documentations. good luck :)